# Why does my cocker spaniel behave inappropriately towards my new maltipoo?

Tags: dogs, behavior, multi-pet-families

My 7yr old cocker spaniel has been an only pet since we've had him at 6 weeks old. We recently got a maltipoo who's now 4 months old (we got him at 6 weeks, but he was confined until all his shots were given). My cocker was getting accustomed to seeing him around.

Now I'm trying for them to interact to be able to play together with my maltipoo on a leash. My cocker only wants to lick his penis or try to hump him. Can someone please explain this behavior as this is all new to me.

Comment: Comment: They are dogs, they see nohtin inappropiate in sexual behavior. But yes, to humans it can be embarassing. Question: I take it they are both not desexed? Will they be?